# Python: Mysqldb connector Version Issue

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and recently installed python 3.5.1. I am trying to establish a connection with mysql server and need relevant version of mysqldb connector for python-3.5.1. 
I have tried to install mysqldb-2.1.2, but it is not compatible with python 3.5.1.
I have searched the required thing but didn't got the compatible version of mysqldb connector.
Kindly somebody tell me, whether the compatible version of mysqldb connector for python-3.5.1 has been released or not? 
If yes, please give a download link.

Thanks in advance

Comment: AFAIK MySQLdb doesn't support Python 3. Use PyMySQL, which is a drop-in replacement for MySQLdb.

Comment: Use `mysqlclient` https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient